# Java object that dereferences itself after a time

Tags: java, memory, dictionary, timer

I have a large HashMap for storing POJOs.
As time goes on, I add more and more POJOs and the map gets bigger and bigger and eventually I run out of memory. 
I want the objects within the map to dereference themselves after a set period of time (so they are effectively being cached).
I was thinking about using timers within the objects but I'm not sure if this is the standard (or proper) way of doing it. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Guava's `Cache`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) ?

Comment: Or something like `java.util.WeakHashMap`?

Comment: Does it have to use a timer? If that's not a hard requirement, an interesting alternative can be a [`WeakHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html), which cleans up an element if its key is no longer used (not referenced and garbage collected)

Comment: Guava's Cache is perfect! Thanks for the input everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I would at least implement an absolute threshold on your map object size (in quantity of objects if you know the POJOs size).  On add, check to see if your size limit will be exceeded, and if so, iterate through to find the oldest MaxCount * N (N is a fraction, probably start with 20% = 0.2) items and remove them.  Because you trim a percentage of the limit (very important, versus a fixed size), adding items is still O(1) (amortized).  If additionally, you want to add a timer to your collection that throws away anything older than some threshold, that would also help you to keep the size manageable in a separate thread without the call to Add taking an exhorbitant amount of time in a few rare cases.